# Apple Developer Apps & Services

Tags: developer-program

I recently enrolled into paid [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) as an Individual.

I'd like to know what otherwise paid apps or services are available for free to members of paid Apple Developer Program?

For e.g., **macOS Server.app**, which is available as a paid app on the Mac App Store, is available for free via a redeem code to registered Apple developers. I am interested in knowing if there are other paid apps or services (Apple or 3rd party) which I am eligible to obtain for free.

Additionally, what are some of the benefits available **only** to registered developers, like the ability to contend for WWDC ticket lottery?

**Note**: What I am interested here in knowing, are the things similar to macOS Server.app which could be obtained by paying, even by non-registered developers, but offered to registered Apple developers for free. I am aware that the various services offered as a part of the paid developer program costs money (technical support incidents, signed certificates), but they cannot be otherwise obtained from Apple by paying and not enrolling into any of the official paid developer programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no other paid apps given away for free to members.

However, you should be aware that various services/features of the developer membership such as support requests and the ability to generate secure certificates, are things that would otherwise cost money.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/

In terms of other perks: beta software releases (well, earlier than the public) and developer account tools. macOS Server would count as either/both of those depending on when you visit the [member download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Matt. Well, I am aware that the many services offered to a registered developer will otherwise cost money (hosting of apps, issuing certificates, support incidents etc.). What I am interested here in knowing are the things similar to macOS Server.app which could be obtained by paying, even by non-registered folks. Clearly, support requests and the ability to generate secure certificates are not along the same lines here.

Comment: Are you a member of the Apple Developer Program yourself? This answer is untrue, macOS Server **is** most certainly given away for free to members via a Mac App Store redeem code; here's a screenshot of macOS Server from the Downloads section in my account: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHtNr.png

Comment: Yes, I am a member. I have edited my answer to state no _other_ paid apps as macOS Server was known about and mentioned in the question. I would class that app as a beta or developer tool depending on when you visit https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: "other" is an extremely important distinction! Thanks for the edit, +1, you may wish to also remove your comment which reiterated the incorrect information

Comment: As mentioned in your most recent edit of the answer, in terms of other perks, can you specify the **developer account tools** which are **only** offered to paid program members and are unavailable to non-program enrolled (free) registered Apple developers?

Comment: That information as written by Apple is at the link I put in my answer from first draft: "Access the resources you need to configure app services, manage your devices and development teams, and to submit new apps and updates." Application Loader is one app that qualifies, the developer website itself, and the iTunes Connect website. i'm not sure which of those you (free) members get access to.